# multiple custom post type on category page

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, archives

Is it possible to have multiple custom post types appear on a category page?

For example, I have a category *Animals* and I can assign it to both these custom post types: *dog*, *cat*

Both cpts use a pre_get_posts filter:

```
function dog_query_post_type($query) {

    if( is_category() &&  $query->is_main_query() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        if($post_type)
            $post_type = $post_type;
        else
            $post_type = array( 'post', 'dog', 'nav_menu_item');

        $query->set('post_type',$post_type);

        return $query;
    }

}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'dog_query_post_type');
```

But only one cpt will appear on the Animals category page.

If I deactivate the plugin for the *dogs* cpt, then any *cat* cpts assigned to Animals will appear on the category page.

I have tried changing the priority settings on the add_filter calls.

And none of this affects the display of normal posts in the category from appearing on the category page.

I'd like to have any post, of any type, appear on the *Animals* page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Whatever filter runs last is going to overwrite whatever ran before it, as you're not adding to post types already set by previous filters, you are replacing it entirely with a different value.

Comment: So obvious I couldn't see it.  Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `$post_type` array, don't replace it...

```
function dog_query_post_type($query) {

    if( is_category() &&  $query->is_main_query() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        if($post_type)
            $post_type[] = 'dog';
        else
            $post_type = array( 'post', 'dog', 'nav_menu_item');

        $query->set('post_type',$post_type);

        return $query;
    }

}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'dog_query_post_type');
```